# How to split the total time with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server.

Table1

```
ID TotalTime

001 12:00:00
002 11:00:00
003 09:00:00
004 08:00:00
005 14:00:00
....
....,

TotalTime Datatype is nvarchar
```

I need to split the total time column in to 3 columns like the below condition

```
First 8 Hours should display in  First column
After 8 Hours the next 2 Hours should display in Second column
After 10 Hours the remaining hours should display in third column
```

Expected Output

```
ID TotalTime Column1 Column2 Column3

001 12:00:00 08:00:00 02:00:00 02:00:00
002 11:00:00 08:00:00 02:00:00 01:00:00
003 09:00:00 08:00:00 01:00:00 
004 08:00:00 08:00:00      
005 14:00:00 08:00:00 02:00:00 04:00:00
....
....,
```

How to make a query for the above condition.

Need Query Help.

Comment: Is a value of 0 instead of null acceptable in columns 2 and 3?

Comment: What is the type of your TotalTime column? Not something like nvarchar, I hope... Could you show us the table definition?

Comment: 1. Can there be minutes & seconds in your `hh:mm:ss` strings? 2. Can hours be greater than 23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case` to split up the time:

```
select  ID
,       case when totaltime > 8 then 8 
             else totaltime end
,       case when totaltime > 10 then 2
             when totaltime > 8 then totaltime - 8
             else 0 end
,       case when totaltime > 10 then totaltime - 10
             else 0 end
from    YourTable
```

Comment: Nitpick: the TotalTime column is missing, and Gopal seemed to want 
`null`s instead of `0`s -- but apart from that: +1